# Achievements and Leaderboars not showing up

Tags: android, client, game-center, leaderboard, achievements

I'm a newbie in android programming, having started a few months ago only. I've always found an answer to my questions up to now, but this particular one seems not to exist. I may be missing something obiouvs but I try to ask anyway.

I'm dealing with google play services implementation in the game I'm developing. I set everything up following step by step more than one guide. They were similar and the resulting code was the same. And it's working fine: I can log in and connect to API's with GoogleApiClient. I set up the achievements and leaderboards in the console and I can even update them and unlock achievements.

The problem is I can't see any of my achievements or leaderboards in the Play Games app by Google. From the console they result published but in the app, if I click on my game, I'm only able to see the description and "other people using this game"; achievements and leaderboards section are missing and I can't figure out how to make them appear. 

I want to underline that if I call inside my app the leaderboards or achievements activity, provided by the google play services library itself, it works. The intent is launched and achievements show up (same thing for leaderboards). So I thought the problem was outside my game code.

So, what am I mistaking? Do I have to change something else in the developer console? Do I have to add something else I didn't notice?

Thanks in advance to everyone who will help me.

Comment: Can you post the code that's relevant to your question?

Comment: Leaderboards and achievements are not showing app in the Google Play Games app so I don't think the problem is in my code.. In other words I don't know what part of my code I should post..

Comment: @AlessandroGiusa The problem, in my case, solved by itself as suggested in the answer. Publish the game and simply wait

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior, it wont show up in the Google Play app until you have published your game.

I have faced the same problem and it showed up as expected when the app went live.

Comment: False. My game app is published. I'm preparing for my second version by adding _Google Play Games_ plugin/package for Unity. I successfully made the first test on login/logout via Google account. However, as I took attempt to open/show leaderboard and achievement UI and nothing happened, even if I decided to publish game services and the results were nothing. To understand my perspective, see [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/124884/showing-google-play-game-leaderboard-ui-not-working-at-all).

Answer (score 0):

So, finally here the answer to that issue. I directly wrote an email to Google support. I was told, they have a kind of activity threshold for each app. Once you hit that, you will see 'MyAchievements' and/or 'Leaderboard' tabs in GooglePlayService app.

So my app [Hardy the Game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=giusa.software.balljumper.android) finally got at least the achievements activated.

Obviously you have to publish the game and do every step required as explained in [Google Play Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/).

Of course you can immediately use your achievements/leaderboards programmatically. Actually, you should do!

For getting those extra tabs just wait and get your app more activity. In my case I developed all achievements and started to share with my friends.

Hope that helped!

Good Programming

Comment: My app is online since October last year and I still don't see the leaderboard in the Google Play Games app. I seem it only in game, via the google leaderboad UI. 

Could you give me the email address of the google support where you wrote your email to? I searched the google page for hours and can't find a support email address.